# Prevent screen captures of individual apps on Windows

Tags: windows, security

Android has a mechanism for an app to tell the system that it does not wish its screen to be captured. This can be used by password managers or apps which display DRM content to prevent eavesdropping or ripping of content.

If an app has [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE) set, this will prevent screenshots, and the recent apps list will only show a title bar but no content. The app will show only on displays considered secure by the system. It’s not a 100% guarantee but it does raise the bar.

Does Windows have a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have this mechanism and it isn't really practical.

In an unrooted Android device applications run with a limited account. In such an environment it isn't difficult to effectively enforce such restrictions. These restrictions would be possible in a Windows 10 tablet but I don't know if they exist. If the device was rooted then applications would be able to bypass restrictions without too much difficulty.

In standard versions of Windows the OS is essentially always rooted. An application running with an elevated admin account could bypass any restrictions that might be set in place. Trying to restrict such an account is an exercise in futility. For most home users running an application with full admin rights is only a few mouse clicks away. Applications able to take unrestricted screenshots would be readily and freely available.